# Primefaces command buttons stopping fileupload when ajax is on

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

got a weird issue, i have a primefaces command button :

```
<p:commandButton action="#{userBean.buttonToUploadText}" value="Submit" icon ="ui-icon-arrowstop-1-n"/>
```

userBean.java

```
public String buttonToUploadText() {
    System.out.println("buttonToUploadText invoked"); //testing to make sure it is called
    return "/upload/uploadText.xhtml";
}
```

all this should do is simply take the user to the upload text page, it does this but whenever i have this button the fileupload does nothing, but the second i edit this command button out and use a normal one the file upload works perfect ? what am i doing wrong

EDIT:

have just found out when ajax is false it works perfectly, why is this ?

Comment: You can't navigate with ajax. A full http request is required for navigation

Comment: @kolossus: that's not true.

Comment: How can i use ajax to navigate correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show all the code, but this problem is recognizable if your PrimeFaces file upload component has a `mode="simple"`. This will generate a native HTML `<input type="file">` without any JS/Ajax support. This requires a command button with `ajax="false"`, exactly as shown in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf).

If you want to be able to upload files and submit the form by ajax, then use `mode="advanced"`. See also the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf).

#### See also:

- [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked/8880083#8880083)